# How to make the emojis from emoji.css bigger?

Tags: html, css, emoji, webflow

Im a coding newbie. I implemented emoji.css via CDN into my page. What I'm trying to do is to make the Icons bigger.

Like here on the bottom: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/emoji.css

How do I do that? I'm using this code to implement the icons into my site:

```
<span class='ec ec-sparkling-heart'></span>
```

Comment: Did you try to increase the font-size?

Comment: They use CSS `content` so you can increase their size using `font-size` as mentioned above.

Comment: you're my hero. thank you so much :)